`dpkg` breakage in bookworm 64-bit?
This morning, while doing a routine apt update followed by apt full-upgrade of 3 packages (dpkg, dpkg-dev, libdpkg-perl) on my RPi Zero 2W, I received the following message:

dpkg: warning: This system uses merged-usr-via-aliased-dirs, going behind dpkg's
dpkg: warning: back, breaking its core assumptions. This can cause silent file
dpkg: warning: overwrites and disappearances, and its general tools misbehavior.
dpkg: warning: See https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#broken-usrmerge.

I've read the linked wiki article, but it makes little sense to me:
Q: Does dpkg support merged-/usr-via-aliased-dirs?

A: No. This approach is considered broken by design and breaks many common expectations.

In dpkg the expected breakage includes:

    failing to notice file conflicts with the subsequent silent file overwrites by f.ex. dpkg, dpkg-divert and update-alternatives,
    files disappearing during package upgrades or diversion installation,
    failing to activate triggers on pathnames,

    failing to find pathnames on dpkg-query -S searches,
    failing to install packages shipping the same filename in real and aliased directories (with rather cryptic errors), f.ex. to be able to install otherwise dependency satisfiable packages needed by old software,

    completely messing up the filesystem by simply using dpkg-deb -x or tar -x. 

If you have a system that has been installed recently (since Debian buster) or switched via the usrmerge hack, you might want to consider using the dpkg-fsys-usrunmess program (but beware that it should not be used in systemd's emergency mode) or reinstalling. For further information see Teams/Dpkg/MergedUsr.

Debian officially only supports merged-/usr-via-aliased-dirs systems. Converting to an unmerged-/usr 
setup might break the system in unexpected ways in the future, including data loss or failure to boot. 

On the surface, this warning appears to contradict itself; i.e. the first line:

Q: Does dpkg support merged-/usr-via-aliased-dirs? Answer: No ...

And then the last line:

Debian officially only supports merged-/usr-via-aliased-dirs systems. Converting to an unmerged-/usr setup might break the system in unexpected ways in the future, including data loss or failure to boot.

Has anyone encountered this before, or understand its meaning?

If you aren't aware of the history, this is something Fedora did more than a decade ago and other distros have been following suit ever since (there is a parallel in the wider Unix world too, I believe).  If you are curious there's probably oodles of pro- and contra- discussion online, IMO the main take away points are:

Historically, the practice was to facilitate systems where the bulk of software would install to the /usr directories, which could be on separate storage which might not be immediately available to the kernel and init system at boot; core things likely to be needed before that would be in the toplevel directories.  But the widespread use of initramfs type systems together with the potential for virtual partitions (eg. via RAID) pretty much obsoleted this issue.

While maintaining the practice atavisticly might be fine, over time it is simply a pointless complication with some pitfalls (eg., binaries with the same name in /bin, and /usr/bin are resolved via $PATH, which then hides the problem...).


The apparent contradiction in that Debian doc has do with tensions between the Debian adaption, which is quite recent, and dpkg's implementation, see:

https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge
https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#broken-usrmerge

By my reading of this, the dpkg people pushed back by saying they can't do this (partially justified by not wanting to, although I suspect a chicken and egg there) therefore Debian should not, but at this point it has all gone ahead.
I did at some point find a list of the actual issues this causes for dpkg and cannot find it again now, but I would not worry too much; RaspiOS is to whatever extent downstream of Debian (I dunno what the ratio is of packages split between the two repos) and while Bookworm has been in release for almost a full year, AFAIK there hasn't been any disasters -- eg., searching U&L for "Debian usr merge" doesn't reveal any posts on the topic since before bookworm was actually released (maybe interesting from there), further implying most Debian users aren't bothered by it.

Thanks - it makes a bit more sense now. But it's still difficult to understand why the two factions cannot see that their feud results only in user confusion.

Isn't there an apparent contradiction in that, lol?  I think both sides might argue they are trying to pursue a path that would resolve user confusion but the other side is being difficult.  Since this isn't really the Judgement of Solomon, I doubt anyone is going to throw up their hands and go, "User confusion?!??!  Please please anything but that!"

Anyway, I've probably presented it as more of a conflict than it currently is; ultimately the problem is that it is taking time to update dpkg, and as ever in the mostly volunteer open source world the people responsible might reasonably observe that if it is so odious to you you should sign up to help -- they'll probably even pay you the same as they are ;)  It isn't a consumer product, which IMO does not mean "worse than" but different in terms of priorities etc.  There is a bit more onus on the user to shoulder some responsibility for themselves, as I guess we have done here.

Does it mean that nothing needs to be done from the user's side other than waiting for things to settle?

@AlexG I think it is more of a concern for packagers.  Some of the "dangers" listed in those doc include stuff like "completely messing up the filesystem by simply using dpkg-deb -x or tar -x" but in the first case, this presumes you are trying to install a package from outside the normal repo (which is not necessarily safe to start with), and normal users almost never have reason to use dpkg manually (apt uses it, but one presumes safely)...

The second case, tar -x, really has nothing to do with dpkg and: 1) You'd need root privileges to make this dangerous, 2) If you do that without checking what's inside what you are unpacking (which is easy), you sort of get what you deserve.

Thank you a lot for your reassuring comments!
